# Eclipse juno: javaw.exe refers multple times to wc.db - causing lock

Tags: eclipse, locking, subversive

When I use `eclipse juno`, my eclipse freezes often or my eclipse loses the svn connection with a project. By coincidence I executed a `svn info` on the command line of my projects and one returned:

```
svn: E200033: database is locked, executing statement 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA recursive_triggers=ON;'
```

When I do a search on who is referring to the `wc.db` (I use `procexp.exe`) I notice the eclipse `javaw.exe` has multiple references to the same `wc.db`. When I close eclipse, or kill the javaw, the lock is indeed removed (svn info returns normal information).

In eclipse I use subversive.

Update: for some time now i use the subclipse svn plugin instead of the subversive plugin and that 'solved' the issue for me.

Comment: This seems to happen also with Netbeans (v7.3b2); the right-click context menu in Windows locks up (Tortoise's context menu items failing to load, probably) and an attempt to `svn update` within the folder from the command line results in this error message. The lock doesn't seem to be permanent, though.

Comment: Confirmed Netbeans problem on Netbeans 8.1 + TortoiseSvn 1.9.2 . When calling TortoiseSVN→Update it may stop with the message "Database is locked". The quick solution is to close Netbeans and try again.